# What is the preferred way to access an Android database (from the phone) and SQLite database (from the PC) with the same API?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

We develop an application that is supposed to run on both PCs and Android mobile phones. Some of the code should be shared on both platforms. As both versions make heavy use of databases (native SQLite on the PC and the built-in SQLite DBs on Android), I was wondering whether there is a good way to write code that accesses both these databases through the same API.

My question is about the preferred way to develop such code. There are ways to use a native SQLite DB on the Android phone, then obviously the code would be identical. The second option would be to develop a small library that has an AndroidDatabaseAdapter and an SQLiteDatabaseAdapter which both implement a common interface and essentially just forward the respective calls. But since I guess that I'm not the first person to have such a problem, I was wondering whether there already exists such a library. Unfortunately, my Google and SO search did not reveal any such library that is slim and does not already come along with ORM and lots more features which I consider as overhead for our purpose.

Comment: I think you'll have to implement some services (a generic term for something that runs) on your PC that can respond to requests to/from the database.  Lots of ways to do it - sockets, http, two cans and a string...

Comment: I did not mean to access both databases at the same time but rather through the same code. I want to be able to write code that can be (almost) identically used on both Android to access the Android DB and on the PC to access a SQLite DB. And I wonder how I preferrably get such an abstraction.